# To skip empty records from a CSV file using Apache Commons CSV

Tags: java, csv

if a CSV file contains three columns and if the values are as given below

```
a,b,c
     //empty line
,,,
a,b,c
```

There are two valid records. Using Apache commons CSV parser, i could easily skip the record which has empty lines. But when the records contain only null values, how to skip it then?

To overcome this, I'm using `String` `equals()` with already constructed empty record. Here is a sample implementation.

```
List<String[]> csvContentsList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withNullString("");
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFormat);

String[] nullRecordArray = { null, null, null};
String nullRecordString = Arrays.toString(nullRecordArray);
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
    try {
        String values[] = { csvRecord.get(0),csvRecord.get(1),csvRecord.get(2) };
        if (!nullRecordString.equals(Arrays.toString(values))) //lineA
            csvContentsList.add(values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // exception handling
    }
}
```

When i don't use the line marked as 'lineA', this implementation gives three records in the `csvContentsList` as below

```
[a,b,c]
[null,null,null]
[a,b,c]
```

Is there any inbuilt way to do this? or any other better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find here another possible solution.

```
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withNullString("");
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFormat);
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser.getRecords()) {
    String values[] = {csvRecord.get(0), csvRecord.get(1), csvRecord.get(2)};
    for (String value : values) {
        if (value != null) {
            // as soon a value is not-null we add the array
            // and exit the for-loop
            csvContentsList.add(values);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**assumend input**

```
a,b,c

,,,
d,e,f
```

**output**

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

**edit** If you can use Java 8 a solution might be.

```
List<String[]> csvContentsList = csvParser.getRecords()
        .stream() 
        .sequential() // 1.
        .map((csvRecord) -> new String[]{
            csvRecord.get(0), 
            csvRecord.get(1), 
            csvRecord.get(2)
        }) // 2.
        .filter(v -> Arrays.stream(v)
                .filter(t -> t != null)
                .findFirst()
                .isPresent()
        ) // 3.
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // 4.
```

1. if the order of lines is important
2. map a csvRecord to a String[]
3. filter on String arrays with at least one non-null value
4. collect all values and return a List

Might need to be amended, depending on your requirements.

Comment: `CSVFormat.Default` already contains `withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)`. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#DEFAULT. And in the question, i have already mentioned that i am able to skip empty lines.

Comment: @Ram I added a Java 8 example using the Stream API.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [StringUtils#isNotBlank()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank(java.lang.CharSequence)) this way:

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(csvRecord.get(0)) 
     && StringUtils.isNotBlank(csvRecord.get(1)) 
     && StringUtils.isNotBlank(csvRecord.get(2))) {        
   csvContentsList.add(values); 
}
```

Comment: From where to get this `StringUtils` class? It is not part `Apache commons CSV`.

Comment: @Ram visit this site to download common lang jar https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi