# How to skip empty lines in CSV file by apache CSV API?

Tags: java, csv

My csv file has delimiter of tab and contains some empty lines. How can I skip the empty lines when reading the file? The following code receives an exception when it encounters empty lines.

```
CSVParser csvFileParser;
CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.newFormat('\t');
csvFileFormat.withSkipHeaderRecord();
csvFileFormat.getIgnoreEmptyLines();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `.withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)` before parsing CSV.

- [Online java compiler demo](http://jdoodle.com/a/8p6)

FYI

- [To skip empty records from a CSV file using Apache Commons CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36714957/2565527)